# How to use adb shell terminate application like android studio's terminate application?

Tags: android-studio, adb

[image]

When i click `terminate application`, it just stop the first Activity and then start prior Activity by itself. What `terminate application` do? How to use `adb` do `terminate application`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Terminate Application` closes or terminates the current application which is either in foreground, or the application which is selected & connected via ADB.

To terminate an app from `adb`:

```
./adb shell am force-stop <yourp-package-name>
```

Comment: how to use `adb shell` do `terminate application`?

Comment: `adb shell am force-stop` will stop process. i only want to stop foreground activity

Comment: `am kill` only kills so called "processes that are safe to kill" & `am force-stop` stops the application.